# Permission denied /var/lib/postfix/master.lock error

Tags: postfix

I recently migrated to a different server at a different location and now I'm experiencing a weird problem:

```
postfix/master[1281]: fatal: open lock file /var/lib/postfix/master.lock: cannot open file: Permission denied
```

I've googled around and can't get it to work. I've checked permission on `/var/lib/` and things look good there:

```
hawk084:/var/lib/postfix# l
total 20K
-rw------- 1 postfix postfix    0 Jan 25 19:06 master.lock
-rw------- 1 postfix postfix 1.0K Jan  6 02:48 prng_exch
-rw------- 1 postfix postfix 8.0K Jan  6 00:43 smtpd_scache.db
-rw------- 1 postfix postfix 8.0K Jan  6 00:43 smtp_scache.db

hawk084:/var/lib/postfix# /etc/init.d/postfix status
postfix is not running.
```

I uninstalled postfix and re-installed it but, nothing fixes this damn problem.

I even removed master.lock but, nothing changed. Postfix is running under "postfix" user account as default.

I have exactly the same configurations as from the older server which is also running on debian squeeze.

Comment: What distribution is this? What are the ownership and permissions for all the directories leading up to this one?

Comment: l /var/lib/
drw-------  2 postfix postfix 4.0K Jan 26 15:51 postfix

Comment: Why is your directory not +x? +x is here to allow directory traversing.

Comment: It is, typo: drwxr-xr-x  2 postfix postfix 4.0K Jan 26 15:51 postfix

Comment: Jan 26 16:38:03 hawk084 postfix/master[10643]: fatal: open lock file /var/lib/postfix/master.lock: cannot open file: Permission denied

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give us the permissions for:

```
/
/var
/var/lib
/var/lib/postfix
```

Most likely one of those 4 folders up above doesn't have the correct permissions. Also, what's the output of running the following:

```
sudo -u postfix /bin/bash
touch /var/lib/postfix/master.lock
```

If it's successful, then the user that writes to master.lock isn't `postfix`, it's a different one.

Comment: Solved... Permissions to /var/lib were not correct: 700, changed to 755 and things worked afterwards. Thanks for replying and helping out.

Comment: Also mine was a problem of permissions on master.lock file. It was 500, moved to 755 and now it's ok. Thank you.